Are these the correct statistical tests to use for my data? Count data for 9 behaviours in 3 age groups
I was hoping you would be able to help me double check if I am using the right tests.
I performed focal studies on 36 deer collecting both the frequency and cumulative time expressed (in seconds) for 9 studied behaviours. The deer were categorised into 3 generalised age groups (small, medium and large). I've used the Shapiro-Wilks test, a generalised linear model and I'm starting to code a Tukey post-hoc analysis.
My question is ~
Age dependent differences in the expression of rutting behaviours
Here is my code in r studio - I haven't yet gotten the Tukey post-hoc test to work but I wanted to check that I was using the right tests before spending more time on it.
# Setting it up 
study_data <- read.csv(choose.files())
study_data_tibble <- as_tibble(study_data)
class(study_data_tibble)

# List of variables
varlist <- c("b_frequency", "b_duration", "gs_frequency", "gs_duration", "pr_frequency", "pr_duration", "m_frequency", "m_duration", "l_frequency", "l_duration", "co_frequency", "co_duration", "cx_frequency", "cx_duration", "e_frequency", "e_duration", "atg_frequency", "atg_duration")

# Shapiro Wilks Test 
wilks_test <- function(data, group_column, value_column) {
  groups <- unique(data[[group_column]])
  wilks_result <- lapply(groups, function(group) {
    group_data <- data[data[[group_column]] == group, value_column]
    group_data <- group_data[!is.na(group_data)]
    if (length(group_data) >= 3) {
      p_value <- shapiro.test(group_data)$p.value
    } else {
      p_value <- NA 
    }
    return(p_value)
  })
  names(wilks_result) <- groups
  
  # Check each element of the test 
  results_summary <- sapply(wilks_result, function(p_value) {
    if (is.na(p_value)) {
      return("NA")
    } else if (p_value < 0.05) {
      return("Significant")
    } else {
      return("Insignificant")
    }
  })
  
  return(results_summary)
}

# Shapiro Wilk results for each variable
for (var in varlist) {
  wilks_result <- wilks_test(study_data_tibble, 'size', var)
  print(paste("Shapiro-Wilk Test for:", var))
  print(wilks_result)
}

# General Linear Model 
fit_glm <- function(var, data) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste(var, "~ size"))
  model <- glm(formula, family = poisson, data = data)
  return(model)
}

# General Linear Model results for each variable
for (var in varlist) {
  glm_result <- fit_glm(var, study_data_tibble)
  print(paste("General Linear Model for:", var))
  print(summary(glm_result))
}

#Testing Tukey Post Hoc 
glm(len ~ 'size', data = study_data_tibble) %>% tukey_hsd()

Here is my data as a tibble:
tibble::tribble(
  ~focal_study, ~size, ~b_frequency, ~b_duration, ~gs_frequency, ~gs_duration, ~pr_frequency, ~pr_duration, ~m_frequency, ~m_duration, ~l_frequency, ~l_duration, ~co_frequency, ~co_duration, ~cx_frequency, ~cx_duration, ~e_frequency, ~e_duration, ~atg_frequency, ~atg_duration,
            1L,   "l",          10L,        518L,           59L,         305L,            3L,          27L,          16L,         23L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
            2L,   "m",           NA,          NA,           63L,         413L,            4L,          32L,          30L,         49L,           5L,         18L,            NA,           NA,            4L,          20L,           3L,         96L,             NA,            NA,
            3L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           21L,         141L,            NA,           NA,          12L,         45L,           NA,          NA,           10L,          52L,            NA,           NA,           4L,         33L,             5L,           18L,
            4L,   "l",          36L,        419L,           45L,         228L,            4L,          29L,           NA,          NA,           6L,         27L,            NA,           NA,            6L,          33L,           1L,          7L,             2L,            9L,
            5L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            6L,          31L,            NA,           NA,           2L,         27L,            11L,           64L,
            6L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           22L,          78L,            5L,          23L,          11L,         46L,           NA,          NA,            5L,          36L,            3L,          10L,           NA,          NA,             3L,           12L,
            7L,   "l",          71L,         92L,            5L,          13L,            NA,           NA,           1L,          4L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            1L,           8L,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
            8L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            5L,          11L,            NA,           NA,           8L,         26L,           5L,         14L,            NA,           NA,            2L,          10L,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
            9L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            2L,           4L,            NA,           NA,           2L,          6L,           2L,          5L,            1L,          14L,            1L,          10L,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
           10L,   "l",           9L,         15L,            6L,          14L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           2L,         12L,             NA,            NA,
           11L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            4L,           8L,            NA,           NA,           1L,          3L,           2L,          6L,            NA,           NA,            1L,           7L,           2L,         17L,             NA,            NA,
           12L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            2L,           5L,            NA,           NA,           6L,         19L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           2L,         20L,             NA,            NA,
           13L,   "l",           6L,        320L,            6L,          22L,           11L,         306L,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            3L,          27L,           3L,        123L,             NA,            NA,
           14L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            3L,           6L,            4L,          45L,           5L,         46L,           1L,          2L,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           4L,         99L,             2L,           11L,
           15L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           18L,          15L,            NA,           NA,          15L,        109L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           3L,        133L,             NA,            NA,
           16L,   "l",          11L,        465L,            5L,          12L,            7L,          84L,           1L,          2L,           1L,          2L,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           9L,        123L,             2L,           13L,
           17L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            9L,          26L,            2L,          32L,          18L,         63L,           5L,          8L,            NA,           NA,            1L,           3L,           1L,          6L,             3L,           18L,
           18L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           14L,          62L,            NA,           NA,           8L,         33L,           7L,         11L,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,             1L,           21L,
           19L,   "l",           7L,         58L,            3L,           5L,            NA,           NA,           1L,          2L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           1L,          6L,             1L,            3L,
           20L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            2L,           7L,            NA,           NA,          10L,         14L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           3L,         18L,             NA,            NA,
           21L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           3L,          5L,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           6L,         82L,             4L,           27L,
           22L,   "l",           1L,        368L,            6L,          29L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            1L,           5L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
           23L,   "m",           1L,          3L,            3L,          21L,            NA,           NA,           3L,          7L,           NA,          NA,            2L,          10L,            2L,          15L,           3L,         24L,             1L,            3L,
           24L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            2L,           6L,            8L,          26L,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            2L,           4L,            NA,           NA,           4L,         26L,             NA,            NA,
           25L,   "l",           NA,          NA,            2L,          16L,            1L,          39L,           NA,          NA,           3L,         13L,            NA,           NA,            4L,          54L,           1L,         64L,             NA,            NA,
           26L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            4L,          38L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           2L,         47L,             1L,           13L,
           27L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            1L,           3L,            NA,           NA,           2L,        146L,             NA,            NA,
           28L,   "l",         231L,        488L,           11L,          98L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           2L,         17L,            NA,           NA,            8L,         106L,           NA,          NA,             NA,            NA,
           29L,   "m",           NA,          NA,           11L,          48L,            2L,          40L,           1L,          6L,           2L,          8L,            1L,           6L,            NA,           NA,           4L,         41L,             1L,            3L,
           30L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           12L,          40L,            2L,          19L,           NA,          NA,           1L,         15L,            3L,          17L,            4L,          23L,           2L,         18L,             1L,           14L,
           31L,   "l",           5L,        465L,            1L,          10L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           1L,          8L,             2L,           20L,
           32L,   "m",           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            3L,          75L,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,          11L,        142L,             2L,           20L,
           33L,   "s",           NA,          NA,            5L,          35L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           1L,         10L,             2L,            7L,
           34L,   "l",           1L,        104L,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           3L,         19L,             NA,            NA,
           35L,   "m",           NA,          NA,           12L,          70L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            NA,           NA,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,             3L,           19L,
           36L,   "s",           NA,          NA,           14L,          50L,            NA,           NA,           NA,          NA,           NA,          NA,            1L,           8L,            NA,           NA,           2L,         24L,             4L,           45L
  )

Thank you :)

In your data, I wonder whether the "NA" values should be 0 values? The "NA" would mean that you had no possibility to observe the behavior, while I suspect that you would have observed the behavior if it had happened. If so, then you should probably have actual values of 0 both for the number of events and for the cumulative duration. Also, your data by their nature (at least for the counts) can't be normally distributed, so no need for the Shapiro-Wilk test. Some argue that normality testing is essentially useless in general.

@EdM thank you for the advice! I'll change the NAs over now, I think my logic was that a high amount of '0's would skew the data towards 0 but I realise now that doesn't make much sense. Do you think that the poisson general linear model and tukey post hoc tests the most correct to use in this scenario? Is there anything different I should be using instead?

@EdM thank you for the detailed answer. The focal observations lasted 10 minutes for each individual. I'm pretty sure the behaviours are mutually exclusive as the deer can't eat whilst grooming or bellow whilst sniffing another deer but I'm not 100% certain in all instances. I will have a look at the Dirichlet-multinomial distribution model and the Markov model.

It's probably best to model all of the data together instead of building separate models for each behavior. How best to do that depends on details of your data and the subject matter.
It's not clear from your data whether the observation durations differed among animals. If they differed then you need to take that into account. For count data modeled with a log link that can be done with an offset term (log of the observation time). For the durations you might include another outcome for the duration of other behaviors, or to use the total observation time to normalize in some way.
If these are mutually exclusive behaviors that don't occur in an ordered fashion and with the choice of one behavior not influencing later choices, then you might consider multinomial regression for the duration data. You would include an "other behavior" outcome as suggested above. That would provide the probability of being engaged in a behavior as a function of your predictors, in a way that takes into account the multiple behaviors.
There are ways to model different types of counts together (multivariate count outcomes) similarly, although I'm not very familiar with them. The Dirichlet-multinomial distribution has been applied in ecology The MGLM package in R provides tools for fitting that type of data.
I suspect, however, that the behaviors aren't chosen independently, and that some behaviors can only occur if some other behavior has already been chosen. In that case the independence assumptions needed for the above approaches wouldn't hold. You then need a multi-state model that takes the different orderings among behaviors over time into account. A Markov model, assuming that only the current state determines the probabilities of other states, might work. Frank Harrell has some resources explaining that approach, including a chapter of his Regression Modeling Strategies. That would probably require evaluating your data as a function of time rather than relying on the summaries that you present here.
